# Auto zoom when uploading shapefile R / Leaflet

Tags: shapefile, r, leaflet, zoom, shiny

I would like to configure an automatic zoom at the canvas of the shapefile layer that I upload. For that it would be necessary that a function automatically detects the latitude and the longitude of this layer but my researches were not conclusive. Do you know any function that could be useful to me?

Server.UI

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(utf8)
library(rgeos)
library(shinyjs)
library(sp)
library(V8)
library(shinyalert)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(raster)


shinyServer(function(input, output, session){


    #--------- ADD LEAFLET MAP --------#

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      enableTileCaching() %>%
      addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery", group = "Esri World Imagery", 
                options = providerTileOptions(minZoom = 2, maxZoom = 17), 
                tileOptions(useCache = TRUE, crossOrigin = TRUE)) %>%

      addTiles(group = "OSM", urlTemplate = "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.de/tiles/osmde/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", 
               attribution = '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors', 
               options = providerTileOptions(minZoom = 2, maxZoom = 17), 
               tileOptions(useCache = TRUE, crossOrigin = TRUE)) %>%

      addMiniMap(toggleDisplay = T) %>%
      addScaleBar(position = 'bottomleft') %>%
      setView(lng = 97.963,lat = 20.380, zoom = 6 ) %>%
      addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("Esri World Imagery", "OSM"))
  })


    #-------- READ SHAPEFILE --------#
  #-------- SAVE IN TEMP FOLDER --------#
     #-------- CREATE A CSV --------#

  uploadShpfile <- reactive({
    if (!is.null(input$zip)) {
      zipFile <- input$zip
      zipPath <- substr(zipFile$datapath, 1, nchar(zipFile$datapath) - 5)
      unzip(zipFile$datapath, exdir = zipPath)
      pwd <- getwd()
      updir <- dirname(zipFile$datapath[1])
      setwd(updir)
      for (i in 1:nrow(zipFile)) {
        file.rename(zipFile$datapath[i], zipFile$name[i])
      }
      shpName <- zipFile$name[grep(zipFile$name, pattern = "*.shp")]
      shpPath <- paste(updir, shpName, sep = "/")
      setwd(updir)
      Layers <- ogrListLayers(shpPath)
      shpName <- readOGR(shpPath)
      shpName <- spTransform(shpName,CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
      shapefile(shpName, paste(shpPath, Layers, "_WGS84.shp", sep = ""))
      write.table(paste(shpPath, Layers, "_WGS84.shp", sep = ""), 
                  file = "info_shp.csv", 
                  row.names = FALSE, 
                  col.names = FALSE, 
                  quote = FALSE)
      shpName
    }
  })



    #-------- ADD SHAPEFILE --------#

  observeEvent(input$zip, {
    data = uploadShpfile()
    map = leafletProxy("map")
    if (!is.null(uploadShpfile())){
      if(inherits(data, "SpatialPolygons")){
        shinyalert("Successful upload !", type = "success")
        cent <- gCentroid(spgeom = uploadShpfile(), byid = FALSE)
        leafletProxy("map")%>%
          addPolygons(data = uploadShpfile(),
              stroke = TRUE,
              fillOpacity = 0.5)
      }

      if(inherits(data, "SpatialPoints")){
        shinyalert("Successful upload !", type = "success")
        cent <- gCentroid(spgeom = uploadShpfile(), byid = FALSE)
        leafletProxy("map") %>%
          addCircleMarkers(data = uploadShpfile(),
              stroke = TRUE,
              radius = 6,
              fillOpacity = 0.9)
      }
    }
  })
```

ui.R :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(utf8)
library(rgeos)
library(shinyjs)
library(sp)
library(V8)
library(shinyalert)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(raster)


shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title ="Sen2extract"),
    sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(

        menuItem("Map", tabName= "carte", icon = icon("globe"))
      )
    ),

    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName ="carte",
            fluidRow(
                fileInput(inputId = "zip", label = "Upload your file (.zip) :", multiple = FALSE, accept = c('.zip')),       
                leafletOutput(outputId = "map", width="100%", height = 940)
            )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Is this a different question to  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325990/automatic-zoom-when-uploading-shapefile-r - because it looks the same. Please edit that one instead of creating duplicates.

Comment: I rewrote this question to insert a reproducible example. I delete the other.

Comment: This is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406598/leaflet-in-r-setview-based-on-range-of-latitude-and-longitude-from-dataset , but my R skills are not enough to suggest an adaptation of that.